# Computational behaviour of Successor

Tags: coq

Print S answers:

```
Inductive nat : Set :=  O : nat | S : nat -> nat
```

Compute S(1) returns:

```
= 2 : nat
```

How is the computational behaviour (performing addition) of S defined?
Thanks.

Addition to simplify the question:

Why does `Compute S(1)` work? It must be specified somewhere that it's the same as adding 1 to a nat number. How this connection is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, so forgive me if this answer seems obnoxious: you are looking at the behavior of S!

This is a unary representation of the naturals. Computing `S n` means tacking an `S` onto the front of `n` and that is all.

The work comes in defining functions on `nat`, where you say (recursively) what to do with all those `S`s (via pattern matching).

I hope that helps, but perhaps you were asking something different...

Comment: Martin, thank you for your answer. I understand now that S is distinguished within Coq, more specifically within the subsystem that deals with naturals.

Comment: Not sure what "distinguished" means. It is part of the standard library, denoting the successor function on nat. What Meven and I are both trying to say is that there is not a deeper breakdown of the behavior of S - unless you are interested in how Coq goes from the unary representation to the familiar decimal representation (but that is not about `S`, per se). The behavior of `S` is as literal as can be: to 'compute' `S n`, simply prepend the nat `n` with the constructor `S`.

It is like the joke from Steve Martin:

"An axe has one moving part; it."

Comment: Martin, please read my addition in the question.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you *are* asking about the translation back-and-forth between unary and decimal. You'll probably have to dig into the source and reference manual. Here is a starting point, at least: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.DecimalNat.html

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by computational behaviour? `S` is the successor function on natural numbers, i.e. the `+1` function.

However in Coq the natural numbers `nat` are defined as an inductive type (the one you got with `Print S`), which contains `0` and is stable by `S`. This is the nice theoretical setting to perform induction and the like, which is why this representation is the default one. Thus `S` is a basic construction from `nat`’s definition, and addition for instance is defined in term of it. Similarly, numerals are just pretty-printing: `1` is really `S 0`, `2` is `S (S 0)`, etc.

This unary representation is unefficient, but this is usually not too much of a concern, because large numbers are rarely encounter in proofs. However, if you look for a more efficient, binary, representation, there is the type `N` from the standard library.

Comment: Meven, thank you for your answer.
By computational behavior I mean that S(1) provides (computes) the nr. 1 nat, while with a definition for P like P : nat -> nat Compute P(1) would obviously not result in 0. So S is specified further somehow

Comment: As for your second part to the question, it is actually the other way around: (the computational behaviour of) addition is _ defined_ in term of `S`. More specifically, `1+n`  precisely reduces to `S n`. So `S` is really the fundamental basic block of natural numbers in Coq, as fundamental as bits are to `int` in C.